# How to change a military time schedule into a standard time schedule

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a military time schedule as shown below:
0500-1300
or
1330-2100
Is it possible to convert said cell values into standard times; 5:00AM - 1:00PM, without having to use a text-to-column function?

Comment: A single cell is 0500-1300 and not two fields?

Comment: s/"standard time"/:Brittisch or American time"/ ? 

(As far as I know for the rest/most of the world 13:30 and friends are the actual standard times)

Comment: Correct, the data is in a single cell, and the time would be "American" time.

Comment: You could create a table of military to civilian times and then concatenate vlookup formulas.  Creating the table might be tedious, but once done, the formulas should be fairly straightforward.